# string variable to index of String array ??? JAVA

Tags: java, string, arraylist, tostring

I have an Array of strings that it working fine, the Strings are being stored in the array however when i want to take a string from the array and place it into a variable im getting an error. I cant understand why

```
    int arraySizelink = 1; 
    String previousUrl ;

ArrayList<String> historyArray = new ArrayList<String>();

previousUrl = historyArray.indexOf(arraySizelink);
```

Thanks in advance.

I have looked on here and google for the answers but i couldnt find anything. sorry if this has been asked before. im still new to java and still learning.

Comment: This does not compile. its not a logcat error its showing as a Syntax error in the IDE

Comment: indexOf an int in a string list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) expects an `Object`. `get` gets the item at the specified index

```
previousUrl = historyArray.get(arraySizelink);
```

Comment: You sir! Are my saving grace. I'm still quiet new to java and as you know its all a learning curve. Thank you very kindly :)

Answer (score 1):

Just some adjustments to get what you want:

```
int arraySizelink = 1; 

// Use the interface to declare the variable
List<String> historyArray = new ArrayList<>(); 
// If you're using Java 7+, no need to repeat the type 
// inside <> when instantiating because its figured out automatically.

// get method would take an index and return an object from the list.
String previousUrl = historyArray.get(arraySizelink);
```